# How to write a GNOME applet with Ruby

Tags: ruby, applet, gnome

Is there a good guide or tutorial for writing GNOME applets with Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code might be useful if you need a ruby-gnome2 statusicon: [sample code](http://github.com/tristil/agile-lamp/blob/60ea296d3721532198faa37f7b805dcdb004cc5f/agilelampclient/lib/agilelamp/statusicon.rb). Here's the [documentation](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?Gtk%3A%3AStatusIcon) for Statusicon. I can't remember what the relationship is between an applet and a statusicon, but I want to say that an applet is just a configuration file that initializes a statusicon class.